# Can I get additional trace information from Liquid XML

Tags: liquid-xml

I'm having problems starting Liquid XML Studio, is there any way to get additional debug information from it to help diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having an issue with the product crashing or hanging, it may be helpful to our support team if you can provide additional debugging information by turning on tracing to a log file as follows:

1 - Login as Administrator.

2 - Backup the file *C:\Program Files\Liquid Technologies\Liquid XML 2016\XmlStudio14.exe.config*.
*Note:* the path is the folder into which you installed Liquid XML.

3 - Edit the file *C:\Program Files\Liquid Technologies\Liquid XML 2016\XmlStudio14.exe.config* and ensure the section below is uncommented

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener"
             type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
             initializeData="C:\Temp\TraceOutput.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

4 - Ensure the Path specified in the config file (*C:\Temp\TraceOutput.log*) exists on your PC (e.g. C:\Temp).

5 - Start Liquid XML Studio.

6 - You should see a file is created in the specified folder (e.g. C:\Temp\TraceOutput.log)

7 - Perform the task which is causing an issue, then close the application.

8 - Send the TraceOutput.log to Liquid Support.

9 - Undo the changes made to *C:\Program Files\Liquid Technologies\Liquid XML 2016\XmlStudio14.exe.config*